# Create and configure iSCSI block storage device in Vagrant

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, vagrantfile, iscsi

I want to attach an iSCSI block device to my vagrant virtual machine, it is not a real device, i just want to simulate one using a file.

for example, If i want to add normal disk device, i may use the following:

```
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do | p |
  unless File.exist?(disk)
    p.customize ['createhd', '--filename', disk, '--size', 1 * 1024]
  end
  p.customize ['storageattach', :id, '--storagectl', 'SATA Controller', '--port', 1, '--device', 0, '--type', 'hdd', '--medium', disk]
end
```

In this code example, I simulate a new hard drive using a file...

The question is, what should be changed to make this acts like an iSCSI device.
Actually, I am using vagrant to test my chef recipe for configuring block storage on my servers .

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can do that -

Look at the specific [virtualbox doc section](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-storageattach) on `storageattach`

> --medium
>       `iscsi`: For virtual hard disks only, this allows for specifying an iSCSI target. In this case, more parameters must be given
>
> When "iscsi" is used with the --medium parameter for iSCSI support --
>   see [Section 5.10, “iSCSI servers”](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch05.html#storage-iscsi) --, additional parameters must or
>   can be used:
>
> --server The host name or IP address of the iSCSI target; required.
>
> --target Target name string. This is determined by the iSCSI target and used to identify the storage resource; required.
>
> --tport TCP/IP port number of the iSCSI service on the target (optional).
>
> --lun Logical Unit Number of the target resource (optional). Often, this value is zero.
>
> --username, --password Username and password (initiator secret) for target authentication, if required (optional).

the following command would attach a iSCSI drive

`VBoxManage storageattach OneExample --storagectl "SATA Controller" --port 0 --device 0 --type hdd --medium iscsi --server 10.0.0.1 --target "<what you have setup on your NAS>" --tport 3260`

Comment: what is target? does it mean the device name in the /dev filesystem?

Comment: no, target is not from the VM, its where is your iSCSI target, if you setup a NAS most probably you have in the console somewhere a  `iSCSI Target Management page`

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand what it is... I just want it to write to a file, like the example i showed in the question...

Comment: to be clear, I do not have a real iSCSI device, I just want to simulate one for my testing to pass... just like the example i provided, there is no real hard drive, it uses a file to simulate it

Comment: well, not sure you can do that for iSCSI device, target is mandatory to attach a iSCSI device on VirtualBox